# How can I use option Weights for fitting?

Tags: fitting

I have the following dataset (time vs. a quantity called $s$):

```
OPD = {{0, 0.0305}, {3, 0.14}, {6, 0.5}, {17, 4.02}, {19, 5.04}, {21, 5.52}, {24, 5.76}};
```

To the above, I have fitted a differential equation, $\dot{s} = \kappa (1 - s/\mu) s$, and obtained the parameters $s(0)$, $\kappa$, and $\mu$ as follows:

```
Bac = ParametricNDSolveValue[{s'[t] == kappa  (1 - s[t]/mu) s[t], s[0] == s0}, s, {t, 0, 24}, {s0, kappa, mu}];
J[s0_?NumericQ, kappa_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ] := Total@Map[(Bac[s0, kappa, mu][#[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 &, OPD];
mini = NMinimize[{J[s0, kappa, mu], 0 < s0 < 2, 0 < kappa < 2, 0 < mu < 7}, {s0, kappa, mu}]
```

The fit looks like:

```
Show[ListPlot[OPD], Plot[Bac[s0, kappa, mu][t] /. mini[[2]], {t, 0, 24}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

I have just learned that *Mathematica* has an option called `Weights`, which can be used to give weights to the data points in order to take into account the uncertainties. It seems to me that, weights can be the standard deviations of the data points (?), which in my case are:

```
std = {0.0021, 0.0707, 0.0566, 0.5091, 0.2546, 0.8485, 0.3111};
```

I appreciate any help for how to include these standard deviations as weights to my data points in the course of fitting.

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit[]` has a `Weight` option that you may try.

Comment: BTW `DSolve` solves your `DE` analytically. `DSolve[s'[t] == kappa (1 - s[t]/mu) s[t], s[t], t]` gives your model as `s[t] -> (E^(kappa t + mu C[1]) mu)/(-1 + E^(kappa t + mu C[1]))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `NMinimize`, use [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) which supports `Weights`. To define the fitting model, use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html).

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{s'[t] == κ (1 - s[t]/μ) s[t],
    s[0] == s0}, s, {t, 0, 30}, {s0, κ, μ}]
NonlinearModelFit[OPD, sol[s0, κ, μ][t], {s0, κ, {μ, 6}}, t, Weights -> (1/std^2)]
```

---

Luckily, however, your differential equation has a well-known [analytic solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), so you can use  fit directly to the solution, provided by [`DSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html).

```
sol = DSolveValue[{s'[t] == κ (1 - s[t]/μ) s[t], s[0] == s0}, s[t], t]
(* (E^(t κ) s0 μ)/(-s0 + E^(t κ) s0 + μ) *)

OPD = {{0, 0.0305}, {3, 0.14}, {6, 0.5}, {17, 4.02}, {19, 5.04}, {21, 5.52}, {24, 5.76}};
std = {0.0021, 0.0707, 0.0566, 0.5091, 0.2546, 0.8485, 0.3111};
pts = MapThread[{#1[[1]], Around[#1[[2]], #2]} &, {OPD, std}];

fitNoWeights = NonlinearModelFit[OPD, sol, {s0, κ, {μ, 6}}, t];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[OPD, sol, {s0, κ, {μ, 6}}, t, Weights -> (1/std^2)];
Show[ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Black], 
 Plot[{fitNoWeights[t], fit[t]}, {t, 0, 25}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Without weights", "With weights"}]]
```

[image]

Note that when using weights, the fit will bind more tightly to the first three data points which have significantly smaller $\sigma$ than the last three points.

Comment: @Anovice, please see the edit.

Comment: @Anovice, oh right, sorry, thanks!

Comment: @Anovice, the order actually matters. "Positional" arguments come first, and named options (such as `Weights->...`) come at the end.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, NMinimize does not have an option "Weights". Only fitting functions have it. However, you my multiply the residues by 1/std^2 to achieve the same effect like:

```
std = {0.0021, 0.0707, 0.0566, 0.5091, 0.2546, 0.8485, 0.3111};
OPD = {{0, 0.0305}, {3, 0.14}, {6, 0.5}, {17, 4.02}, {19, 5.04}, {21, 
    5.52}, {24, 5.76}};
Bac = ParametricNDSolveValue[{s'[t] == kappa   (1 - s[t]/mu)  s[t], 
    s[0] == s0}, s, {t, 0, 24}, {s0, kappa, mu}];
J[s0_?NumericQ, kappa_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ] := (1/std^2) . 
   Map[(Bac[s0, kappa, mu][#[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 &, OPD];
mini = NMinimize[{J[s0, kappa, mu], 0 < s0 < 2, 0 < kappa < 2, 
   0 < mu < 7}, {s0, kappa, mu}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: In a statistical sense, fitting using standard deviations is more appropriate.

Comment: @DanielHuber, I believe you have to _divide_ by $\sigma^2$ (smaller $\sigma$ => larger contribution), namely `(1/std^2) . Map[...]`. Then, the fit also looks [more convincing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDS6X.png).

Comment: I didn't check Daniel's code, so perhaps some parameter ranges need to be fixed. But still, when you are comparing by eye, you are not taking into account the error bars. Your fit is worse for the first three points, but they have very small uncertainties so the fit should be better there.

Comment: @Domen You are 100% right. I corrected my mistake. Thank you for your hint.